# how to separate aiff channels and save them in wav format?

Tags: python, audio, channel, aiff

I have a database of sound files saved in aif format including 19 channels each. To further process them i need to save each channel separately in wav format. I have used aifc and audioread modules to get basic info on each file but none of them have an option of splitting the channels. I would be grateful for help!

In:

```
with audioread.audio_open('1.aif') as f:
print(f.channels, f.samplerate, f.duration)
```

Out:

```
19 2000 900.0
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Have you tried the `pydub` library. [Here](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub/issues/165) is an example on how to split more than two channels. Additionally you need `FFmpeg` to load `*.aif` data. [Here](http://blog.gregzaal.com/how-to-install-ffmpeg-on-windows/) the link to install `FFmpeg` (on Windows).

Comment: I have followed your guidelines but i cannot save the outcome of my conversion (?)